# WordPress add_action bug?

Tags: wordpress

When a single array of objects is passed as an array to `do_action`, `add_action` will see it as an object, not as an array. Is it a bug?

```
/* Correct if $order is not object*/
$orders = array();
$orders[] = 'abc';

add_action('action123', 'func123');
function func123($orders){
    //$orders will be array here (CORRECT)
}

do_action( 'action123', $orders); 


/* BUG: if $orders is an object */
$orders = array();
$orders[]=new stdClass();

add_action('action123', 'func123');
function func123($orders){
    //$orders will be non-array here (BUG?)
}

do_action( 'action123', $orders);
```

Comment: According to your code, shouldn't `$orders->name='Order1';` be `$orders[0]->name='Order1';` instead?

Comment: How are you checking the type of `$orders` in your action hook? Are you sure you're not looking at the type of the first element of the `$orders` array by accident?

Answer (score 0):

Great question, I didn't realize this myself until I tried it out, but this is expected and intentional behavior (only for an array that has an object as the only item), as documented in the comments at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/
And if you look at the code for do_action(), you'll see the same.

Incidentally, your example code throws an error when you try to set a property on the array:

```
PHP Warning:  Attempt to assign property 'name' of non-object in object-test.php
```

Additionally, make sure you always add_action prior to do_action for the "hooked" function to have any effect.